# What is wrong in this short MATLAB code?

Tags: matlab

The code below attempts to plot the graph based on the equations shown in this figure. The initial parameters are given in the code.  I get errors even with this small code. Where did I get it wrong?
The F-function refers to hypergeometric function.

[image]

```
alpha = 4;
delta = 2/alpha;
P_c = 1;% 
P_d = 1;
T = 1;
%Tplot= linspace(-7.5, 10, 2.5); %referring to T % on the x-axis
Tplot=10^(-7.5/10):10^(2.5/10):10^(10/10); based on @Nakini answer
lambda_c = 0.01;
lambda_d = [0.002,0.01, 0.05]; 
mu = (delta/(1-delta)).*Tplot.* hypergeom([1, 1-delta], 2-delta, -Tplot);
v = (Tplot.^delta).*gamma(1-delta).*gamma(1+delta);
for k = 1:3 % from Dr Core's Edit
p_d(:,k) = lambda_d(k)./((lambda_d(k) .* (v + 1) + lambda_c.*(P_c/P_d).^delta).*v);
p_c(k,:) =  lambda_c./((lambda_c*(mu + 1) + lambda_d(k).*P_d/P_c).^delta).*v);
end
plot (Tplot, p_c);
hold on
plot (Tplot, p_d);
```

Edit: I have edited the code based on answers from @Doctor Core and @Nakini. The modifications made have been highlighted in the code. However, I seem not to get it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The use of `linspace` is not entirely correct. If you want something similar to the plot, you need to do: `Tplot= linspace(-7.5, 10, 8);` or `Tplot= -7.5:2.5:10;`.
2. Are you sure that you need to use the value of **Tplot** as it is? It seems like T is in db.
3. If option-2 is correct, then

   - `hypergeom` function causes a problem when `Tplot == 0`. Matlab throw a `division by zero` error. I am not sure what this function is doing, though. But I can guess that the function(s) has a value between 0 and 1 when T is 0db.
   - For all **-ve** values of Tplot, you are going to get complex numbers from `hypergeom`
   - You are also going to get complex numbers for `v` when Tplot is **-ve**
4. As **p_c** and **p_d** are dependent on **v**, you will get complex numbers as long as **v** is complex.

In short, you need to check the values of **T**. And once you use positive values of T everything will fall into place, I guess. Of course, you need to take care of `syntax` while evaluating expressions like `lambda_c(mu + 1)`.

**EDIT**

Here is the correct version of your code:

```
alpha = 4;
delta = 2/alpha;
P_c = 1;% 
P_d = 1;
T = -10:2.5:10;
%Tplot= linspace(-7.5, 10, 2.5); %referring to T % on the x-axis
% Tplot=10^(-7.5/10):10^(2.5/10):10^(10/10); %based on @Nakini answer
Tplot=db2pow(T); %based on @Nakini answer
lambda_c = 0.01;
lambda_d = [0.002,0.01, 0.05]; 
mu = (delta/(1-delta)).*Tplot.* hypergeom([1, 1-delta], 2-delta, -Tplot);
v = (Tplot.^delta).*gamma(1-delta).*gamma(1+delta);
col = ['-og'; '-or'; '-ob'];
figure;hold on; grid on;
for k = 1:3 % from Dr Core's Edit
    p_c =  lambda_c./(lambda_c*(mu + 1) + (lambda_d(k).*(P_d/P_c).^delta).*v);
    p_d = lambda_d(k)./(lambda_d(k) .* (v + 1) + lambda_c.*(P_c/P_d).^delta.*v);
    plot (T, p_c, col(k, :), 'MarkerFaceColor', col(k,3));
    plot (T, p_d, col(k, :), 'MarkerFaceColor', col(k,3));
end
set(gca, 'XTick',T);
xlabel('T(db)')
hold off;
```

And the output is:
[image: Output]

Comment: can't I use the exact value for the Tplot since its what we have in the graph?

Comment: @Abdulhameed, I don't think so. If you use the exact values then you are going to get complex numbers for `v` and `mu`. In `db-sclae`, if some value is negative means that the ratio is in between 0 and 1.For example, -7.5db voltage gain means  v_out/v_in = 0.42.

Comment: I made edits to the code, but I am not sure where else I might have gotten it wrong.

Comment: Update your code with: `p_d(k,:) = lambda_d(k)./((lambda_d(k) .* (v + 1) + lambda_c.*(P_c/P_d).^delta).*v);
    p_c(k,:) =  lambda_c./((lambda_c*(mu + 1) + lambda_d(k).*(P_d/P_c).^delta).*v);`

Comment: Thanks I have updated it. Seems I still have to check the Tplot again. Now the plots are quite different.

Comment: @Abdulhameed, your edited code is almost correct with some bugs. I fixed and updated the same in my answer.

Comment: Please, could I have an alternative to `Tplot=db2pow(T)` I don't have signal processing toolbox

Comment: @Abdulhameed, sure. Use your method of generating Tplot which is `Tplot=10.^((-10:2.5:10)/10)`.

Comment: Thanks @Nakini, well answered, well presented, well received and well appreciated. Please I would like to remove the graph in the question. I hope you do not mind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171344/discussion-between-nakini-and-abdulhameed).

Answer (score 1):

I spotted two kinds of mistakes:

1. you left out the operator `lambda_c(mu + 1)` should be `lambda_c*(mu + 1)` this happened at least twice.
2. seems you are trying to generate 3 curves for `p_d` using a 3x1 `lambda_d` with a 10x1 `Tplot`.  Matlab vectorization doesn't work that way.  You should either use a for loop or do something smart (and hard to read) with 2D arrays.  Hint: make `p_d` a 10x3 array.

Try

```
for k = 1:3
    p_d(:,k) = lambda_d(k)./((lambda_d(k) .* (v + 1) + lambda_c.*(P_c/P_d).^delta).*v);
end
```